# What does the structure 'be to be past participle' mean?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrasal-verbs

In this following context, what does the structure 'be to be + participle' mean?

Does it mean the same as 'be to + verb'?

Should I take its meanig as: 'should' or 'must'?

Context:

> The first question “Has man a free will?” is to be rejected for the
> reason that, beside these ever-changing mental and physical phenomena,
> in the absolute sense no such thing or entity can be found that we
> could call “man,” so that “man” as such is merely a name without any
> reali ty.

Source: P. 41
"The Fundamentals of Buddhism" by Nyanatiloka Mahathera

Comment: As Billy's link suggests, "is to be rejected" here means "should be rejected".

Comment: @ralph.m: More precisely, *is **intended** to be rejected* (according to the current plan). The condemned man who says *Woe is me, for I **am to be** hanged in the morning!* probably doesn't think he *should* be hanged!

Comment: @ralph.m - 'is to' can also mean 'is going to', 'is scheduled to' , or, (slightly old-fashioned or formal UK) 'is required to'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers and michael-harvey — We don't really know the context, so we can't say for sure if the meaning is "intended to" or "should be". Either is possible, and that's how I read it out of context.